# как узнать роль пользователя в voyager Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```php
public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
{
  return $query->where('author_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

> #### Error: Call to undefined method App\Auth::user()

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо подключить `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`:

```php
use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`;
```